# My Lexus goes off when I turn my AC on

Tags: ac

Good day everyone

Please help me with your thoughts and suggestions...I am having some problems with my 2007/08 ES 350 Lexus...when ever I turn my AC on..my engine goes off...my car has a manual compressor..please help me

Comment: Only when you are at idle, what about if you are doing 3000rpm cruising in the fast lane?

Comment: My engine goes off on both cases...please help

Comment: does it die instantly or shudder to a halt? if it dies instantly the compressor may be seized or seizing but, then this may normally have destroyed the belt so it could be an electronics issue

Comment: is it dying electrically? does the engine just stall? is there anything else you notice when this happens? can you be more specific with the year? is it an 07 or an 08?

Comment: It's a 2007 ES 350 Lexus...the Engine goes off once I on my AC...that's all I noticed...nothing else...so any good professional advise will be greatly appreciated..Thank you..